# Good Practice of Using Implicits in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

Are there any objective reasons to / not to use implicit parameters everywhere in code just to shorten the number of arguments that should be passed

I have a REST API. Each call of an end-point has a unique id that should be passed literally in EVERY function that is being triggered by the call for debugging purposes. A first thought that comes up to eliminate explicit passing of the parameter is to make it an implicit parameter in each function.  But then, my intuition tells me that it is a misusage of implicits (though I don't have firm arguments not doing so).

Could be such approach justified by convenience reasoning where the gain is only removing a single parameter and assumed to be a good practice for the situations like mine?

Comment: Sadly this probably will be closed due being opinion based. However, I would like to share my two cents. Effectively I would not pass this id _implicitly_ _(specially if it is a simple type like **Int** or **String**)_. I would either pass it _explicitly_ all way down, create my own data type **Request** that has all the information of a call _(including the ID)_, thus minimizing the number of explicit parameters. Or maybe use a **Reader[Id]** to compose all the calls _(Note that I would create my own **ID** type)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you for the reply! I feel the same way, but I was wondering if there are objective reasons not doing so. One of my concerns was performance, but digging into literature has cleared it for me that implicits are being very efficiently resolved in Scala, so I am not sure if it is still a legitimate argument.

Comment: And avoid as much as possible "auto-magic" implicit conversions (!= type classes)

Comment: @cchantep Well, with "auto-magic" conversions I can understand that it could have performance implications. However, is it also the case with just implicit parameters?

Comment: @ClassNotFoundException implicits do not have any overhead ver normal parameters, they are resolved at compile time and at bytecode level they are just normal parameters. -  The reasons for not using implicits too much, is because they are like black magic, if you abuse it, you will regret it. First they are resolved by type, thus technically speaking there should only be one and only one implicit **Int** on all the history of the existence itself... which probably does not, however there is only _"one"_ **Functor[List]**. So, implicits are ok for **Typeclasses** and for **Extension methods**.

Comment: @ClassNotFoundException The argument for not using **implicit conversions** is not performance _(actually almost no decision in Scala is taken due performance, you should not care too much about micro optimizations, specially before doing any kind of benchmark)_. **implicit conversions** are discouraged because they happen without any control of the user, they can change the semantics of the code without anyone noticing it, and it makes really confusing to read the code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It makes sense. What about Typeclasses? Are there any cons  and risks related to passing them implicitly in each function?

Comment: @ClassNotFoundException **typeclasses** are meant to be passed _implicitly_ first because that is the ergonomics you want to have, second because in general _(not always though)_ there is only one instance of each **Typeclass** for each type. I would recommend you to move this discussion to the gitter channel, since this is not something anyone can objectivily answer and this has become more like a chat.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez from what you are saying, I understand that in my case it is alright to pass the implicit parameter if it is a Typeclass? Since it is being used only for logging

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you, disregard my last question please. It seems to me to be clear now what you say

Answer (score -3):

I think that this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It is primarily opinion based and it is not completely clear what you are asking.

I think that passing around "context" type parameters like a request id is a fairly conventional use for implicit arguments in Scala, so I would consider your proposal good practice.

> I don't feel comfortable using implicit parameters everywhere in code just to shorten the number of arguments that should be passed.

Why not?

Comment: Maybe I need to reformulate my question then. I am looking for objective reasons not to pass implicit parameters everywhere in code in the sake of shortening the number of parameters that should be passed. Is it better this way?